# Conflict between data protection laws and import export laws regarding cryptography

Tags: data-protection, cryptography

### Main question:

[Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) laws restrict import of cryptography however data protection laws demand it. Which laws prevails?

### Background:

Under the [Wassenaar Arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassenaar_Arrangement) going many countries control or ban may the use of cryptography required for secure https calls done. However data protection laws demand secure passage like HTTPS.

### What data transmitted or not

(Example only) It is IP address followed nothing more being transferred.

### Jurisdiction:

Though applicable to many countries accros for wassenaar .

They restricted cryptography while asking for data to be protected really.

### Example

Someone wants to develop an android app that retrieves verbal version number of the app over https as ip must be done protected following are useful big links:

[Countries with Cryptography Restrictions](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#sa)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_the_import_of_cryptography)

Comment: Cryptography laws prevent https but data follwing protection laws promote it good .

Comment: If doing X without Y is illegal, and doing Y is illegal, then you may not do X. You must follow all laws, and if you can't follow all laws while doing something, then you just can't do it.

Comment: Thousands of apps use cryptography.

Comment: well, then, either it's not illegal for them, or they don't care.

Answer (score 2):

Import and export restrictions on cryptography generally do not **prevent** the use of cryptography. They merely regulate it, often requiring a license, and may restrict who may use it or for what purposes. Also, such laws do nothing to restrict cryptography developed or manufactured in teh country where it is to be used, although other laws may impose restrictions on domestic cryptography, depending on the country involved.

In most countries, importing or downloading a browser that implements the https protocol, or a crypto library that can be used with a browser to implement that protocol, is not prohibited, so data protection laws can be complied with.